# Postgres Average Weighted

Tags: weighted-average

I looked up several finding average weight questions posted in SO but none quite match my requirement.

This is what is expected.

The Postgres table stores the following fields.

[Link to Database Table Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!As4eJ_66iyRPgQwwbbPHvGAQwelq)

Taking a reference from the screenshot above, I need to know what is the function or query I need to create in Postgres so that when an entry is inserted in between 02-Jun-16 and 23-Jun-16, the table will recompute all the relevant value and update the 3 columns G, H, I.

Comment: Someone suggested to use recursive CTE in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426878/calculating-the-weighted-average-cost-of-products-stock

Comment: In CTE, I cannot perform update. So how else I can I do it efficiently?